# Wordpress + Divi: Custom Section Toggle

Tags: php, wordpress, function, divi

I have a child theme editing the main-structure-elements.php file from the Divi parent theme. I have tried to override this file by moving it into the child theme and making the changes there, as well as modifying the functions.php file to require that file, still no luck.

I just need to add a toggle to the Divi sections that adds a css filter. This is the code I have written in the main-structure-elements.php file which works great in the main divi file but is unrecognized if added just in the child theme file.

```
public function get_fields() {
    $fields = array(
        
        'fullpage_height'              => array(
            'label'            => esc_html__( 'Enable Fullpage', 'et_builder' ),
            'type'             => 'yes_no_button',
            'option_category'  => 'configuration',
            'options'          => array(
                'off' => et_builder_i18n( 'No' ),
                'on'  => et_builder_i18n( 'Yes' ),
            ),
            'default'          => 'off',
            'description'      => esc_html__( 'Here you can select whether or not your page should have Full Height enabled. This must be enabled on all sections to function', 'et_builder' ),
            'tab_slug'         => 'advanced',
            'toggle_slug'      => 'layout',
            'default_on_front' => 'off',
        ),
```

this code then is triggering this code later in that same file.

```
if ( 'on' === $fullpage_height ) {
        $this->add_classname( 'fullpage-vertical' );
    }
```

I have been working on this for days, any insight would be a life saver

Answer (score -2):

Did you try run this code as snippet using plugin "Code Snippets"? Maybe at this way the code will work fine.